# How can use virtual file system in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Anyone can help to how to use virtual file system in GAE. I want to store some data, which is returning from the server. I tried to store it to '/war/WEB_INF' but its giving error:

```
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/war/WEB-INF/home" "write")
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Google App Engine, you cannot have access to the local filesystem. You can use other options to store your data like the Datastore or the Blobstore. This depends on your specific needs, size of the files, etc.

For more information take a look at [Datastore Storage Options](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) and [Blobstore Java API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/).

Hope this helps.